# Rails : send value in Ajax to controller when tabs are selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hello I am trying to send the value of the data to the rails controller based on the nav-tabs selected in my view such that i could perform rendering options based on that

My view part:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"  id="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#select1" data-toggle="tab" id="select1">tab1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#select2" data-toggle="tab" id="select2">tab2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#select3" data-toggle="tab"   id="select3">tab3</a>/li>
</ul>  
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active " id="select1">
    <%= render 'form1'%>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane " id="select2">
    <%= render 'form'  %>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane " id="select3" >
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller part :

```
def index
  select_id=params[:select]
end
```

Is there anyway to send the value "select" based on the tab select if tab1 and tab2 selected I need to pass 1 and if tab3 I need to pass the value 2 based on Ajax so that I could render the form based on the value sent through Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So How I made this work is using Javascript since I already had a AJAX Call from the tabs and conflicts occurred

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function clickme(obj,data1,data2){
     $.ajax({url: 'urlhere',
     data: {id:data1,id2:data2},
     dataType: "script",
     method: 'get'
    });      
   }
</script>
```

so changed the HTML as

```
  <li><a href="#select2" data-toggle="tab" id="select2" onclick=clickme("this,data1,data2)>tab2</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add data-attributes into your tabs

```
<div class="tab-pane active " id="select1" data-numid="1">
```

Retrieve it by

```
var num = $(".tab-pane.active").attr('data-numid')
//use num in your ajax request
```

Comment: do I need to have a submit button for this ? or the Ajax with submit when the tab is selected ?

Comment: Much better when the tab is selected

Comment: I need to submit the value to the controller so that I could retrieve the data based on the variable into a div for the current tab ..

Comment: where do i place this ajax request code ? in index.js.erb?

Comment: Anyway, are your forms very huge to use ajax, instead of loading them all on page load like the current code? If its not that huge it would be better not to use ajax to load them.

Comment: its huge and I need to retrieve data without refreshing the page using Tabs and Ajax

Comment: You have to create a js or coffee file like the app/assets/javascripts/formLoader.js.coffee

and include it in your js manifest file (application.js)

Sorry have to go.